# undefined method , Ruby on rails , not able to read database properly postgresql

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-view-controller

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `experiences' for #<Profile id: 2, name: nil, job_title: nil, total_experience: nil, career_highlights: [], overview: nil, primary_skills: [], secondary_skills: [], user_id: 2, created_at: "2022-01-12 17:40:01.237665000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-01-12 17:40:01.237665000 +0000">
```

error raised here :

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/profile/experience', collection: profile.experiences %>
```

this is my experience.rb

```
<%= render 'shared/edit_sub_section' do %>
    <%= experience.text_field :company, value: experience.object.company, placeholder: "Company" %><br/>
    <%= experience.text_field :position, value: experience.object.position, placeholder: "Position" %><br/>
    <%= experience.date_field :start, value: experience.object.start, placeholder: "Start date" %><br/>
    <%= experience.date_field :end, value: experience.object.end, placeholder: "End date" %><br/>
    <%= experience.text_area :description, value: experience.object.description, placeholder: "Description" %><br/>
    <%= render 'shared/input/buttons/delete', type: experience %>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb contains experiences table
and foreign keys

```
add_foreign_key "educations", "profiles"
  add_foreign_key "experiences", "profiles"
  add_foreign_key "profiles", "users"
  add_foreign_key "projects", "experiences"
```

Comment: For profile.experiences to work, you have add association in the profile model.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: have you added 'experiences' association in your profile model?

Comment: How does your `Profile` model look like?